# Doing a range lookup in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a list of non-overlaping ranges (ranges of numbers, e.g. 500-1000, 1001-1200 .. etc), is there an elegant and fast way to do lookup by only passing a number? I could use List.BinarySearch() or Array.BinarySearch() but I have to pass the type of the range object (Array.BinarySearch(T[], T)), I can pass a dummy range object and get the job done (only do the comparison with the range start) but I was wondering if this can be done in a cleaner way by only passing an integer and getting the range object, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This is going to be very dependant on what version of .Net

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Three options:

- Create a dummy Range and suck it up. Urgh.
- Hand-craft a binary search just for this case. Not too bad.
- Generalise the binary search for any IList and a TValue, given an IRangeComparer. I'm not wild on the name "TRange" here - we're not necessarily talking about ranges, but just finding the right place based on a comparison between two different types.

The third option would go *something* like:

```
public interface IRangeComparer<TRange, TValue>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns 0 if value is in the specified range;
    /// less than 0 if value is above the range;
    /// greater than 0 if value is below the range.
    /// </summary>
    int Compare(TRange range, TValue value);
}


/// <summary>
/// See contract for Array.BinarySearch
/// </summary>
public static int BinarySearch<TRange, TValue>(IList<TRange> ranges,
                                               TValue value,
                                               IRangeComparer<TRange, TValue> comparer)
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = ranges.Count-1;

    while (min <= max)
    {
        int mid = (min + max) / 2;
        int comparison = comparer.Compare(ranges[mid], value);
        if (comparison == 0)
        {
            return mid;
        }
        if (comparison < 0)
        {
            min = mid+1;
        }
        else if (comparison > 0)
        {
            max = mid-1;
        }
    }
    return ~min;
}
```

Apologies if I've got any off-by-one errors. I haven't tested it at all, but it does at least compile :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to use your code. One little thing though, Compare() should return less than 0 if value is above the range and vice versa.

Comment: If you are going to use his code, shouldn't you accept it as the answer

Comment: Fixed doc comment for IRangeComparer.

Comment: For reference: I’ve written a functional implementation of the above code for `IComparable<T>` values at [Doing a range lookup in C# - how to implement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948205/doing-a-range-lookup-in-c-sharp-how-to-implement/8949322#8949322).

Comment: Isn't there a built-in .NET class by now that could be used for this purpose? I see we have `SortedList`, but I don't need a value to go along with my ranges.

Comment: @JonathanWood: I don't know of anything, no.

Answer (score 1):

If you have .Net 3.5 or above, try

```
foundRange = yourList.Where(range =› range.BottomNumber ‹= searchInt && range.TopNumber ›= searchInt).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That's going to be O(n) - it'll work, but I think we can do better :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of ranges and are really concerned about performance you could create an [AVL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379573(vs.80).aspx) [type of tree](http://webpages.ull.es/users/jriera/Docencia/AVL/AVL%20tree%20applet.htm) consisting of the range(min,max) pairs, but sorted on the lowest part of the range.

However, if you don't have a lot of ranges to sort things into, this is a lot of work for virtually no gain.