# .net4 BinarySearch in a sorted List

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I want to use the binary search option on a sorted list in c# 4.0. I have been looking at older binary searches:

[How would I search a range of ranged values using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461439/how-would-i-search-a-range-of-ranged-values-using-c-sharp)

I would like some help in how I would do a range search between two dates using the binarySearch. I have a list which has many dates and I want to quickly search through this large list between two dates and return the found items if there is any. I though a binary search would be quick as it will quickly get rid of unnecessary comparisons as it is sorted.

Comment: Have you looked at SortedList-of-T?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch.aspx

Comment: Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565844/c-sharp-binarysearch-a-listt-by-a-member-of-t

Comment: I voted to close this. You're showing no effort as to what you have tried or where you're stuck. Instead you're just asking for code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list is List and your dates are DateTime you can do a List.BinarySearch(...) in this way

```
List<DateTime> l;
int startIndex = l.BinarySearch(beginDate);
int endIndex = l.BinarySearch(endDate);
```

At this point you've the range of dates between beginDate and endDate. Now you can get them iterating between the two indexes.

If you want to find the closest date in case the exact date was not found then you can't perform a binary search. In that case you've to re-implement your data structure (in your case your List must be replaced by some powerful structure) to support a range search algorithm that consist of a binary search tree where you will store each year and each node will contain a new binary search tree that will contain all the month belonging to that year now each node will contain a new binary search tree that will contain all the days of that month and so on.

Comment: What about when `beginDate` doesn't exist in the list. i.e when it differs in hours? what should OP do when index is negative?

Comment: That depends on what you wanna do. If the index is -1 that means that the beginDate doesn't exist so you can show a message box saying that the beginDate was not found or in case the beginDate or endDate are not found you can perform a "find nearest"

Comment: When you do a range search, you will probably not get an *exact* match.  Since DateTime comparison requires an equality even in seconds. Therefore getting an negative index is normal case, and should be handled in the code, not by giving a message. I think your answer should include all of these.

Comment: @L.B i've edited the original answer explaining you how to do the find nearest. If you have any doubt please let me know

Comment: I would expect you to say "if you get a negative index, say startIndex, then you can use `~startIndex` as an offset to start the search."

Comment: `If value is not found and value is less than one or more elements in array, a negative number which is the bitwise complement of the index of the first element that is larger than value` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb.aspx

Comment: Same is true also for endDate :)

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- You have a collection, an ordered list or array of a given type T.
- Said collection is a *bag* (duplicates are allowed) and not a *set* (unique items).

You need to

- Do a binary search to find an item meeting your your "from" criteria, the lower bound.

  Since this is a binary search and you have a *bag* rather than a *set*, you are not guaranteed that this is the first item in the collection meeting the from criteria. That means that you need to...
- Back up to the first item matching the "from" criteria. This is a sequential operation.

  At this point, you have the starting point for your iteration. All you have to do is iterate sequentially over the collection from this point...
- **while** the "thru" criteria, the upper bound condition is true.

This might suggest the use of a custom comparer for both the upper and lower bound tests.

It might also suggest a solution in the form of a LINQy extension method.

Good Luck!

Comment: Not sure if OP has a bag or set. If he means `SortedList` then it doesn't allow duplicates.