# Binary search on list

Tags: c#, list, binary-search

I have the following code which fetches a country ID based on the IP address:

```
countryID = GetAllCountryIPRanges().Single(c => c.BeginIPNum <= intIp && intIp <= c.EndIPNum).CountryID;
```

It's unfortunately quite slow as there's ~200,000 records.  The ranges do not overlap, and `GetAllCountryIPRanges()` is in ascending order by `BeginIPNum`.

How do I implement `.BinarySearch()` on this list to find the correct record?

Comment: If you need a quick access to values maybe it's worth to consider a `Dictionary` instead of some `IEnumerable` collection.

Comment: Dictionary isn't suitable as we're searching on an imprecise value falling between stored ranges (see the working but slow example)

Comment: what if you keep ranges in a `Tuple` and used the `Tuple` as key?

Comment: What do you mean implement? There  is a default implementation for List<T>.BinarySearch(T item). You can use that right?

Comment: In this case I would implement Binary Search myself. Since Binary Search is so easy to implement it seems like the quirks of implementing a comparer for use with the built in binary search are not worth it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doing a range lookup in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454250/doing-a-range-lookup-in-c)

Comment: What do you mean by slow? Give us some reference. For some apps few seconds could be "slow" and for some others few ms could be "slow".

Comment: O(N) vs O(log(N)) is quite a good reference for "slow"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List has a binary search method but since binary search is so easy to implement and since the IComparator you would need to define is so complex due to the range thing I suggest you implement the binary search method

Something like this (NOT TESTED!)

```
public static IPRange BinarySearch(List<IPRange> source, int intIp)
{
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = source.Count;
    while (endIndex >= startIndex)
    {
        int middleIndex = startIndex + (endIndex - startIndex) / 2;
        if (source[middleIndex].BeginIPNum <= intIp && intIp <= source[middleIndex].EndIPNum)
        {
            return source[middleIndex];
        }
        else if (source[middleIndex].BeginIPNum < intIp)
        {
            startIndex = middleIndex + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            endIndex = middleIndex - 1;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Assuming the List is sorted and there are no overlapping ranges.

Comment: "binary search is so easy to implement" - wait what :P?

Comment: Why is defining a Comparer complex?

Comment: Because what he is searching for is actually a single number into a range. This means that he has to define equality as either one of the ranges being inside the other and that's only the equality. He needs to define less than as the end index of one being bigger than the start index of the other and the reverse for greater than. All this needs to reside in an inner class and implement the interface. Then he needs to create a Range object with both limits being the searched number and then he needs to call the built-in BS with that range and the comparer object. Implementing BS seems easier.

Answer (score -1):

Gotta love the elegance of recursion... (not tested)

```
public static IPRange BinarySearch(IList<IPRange> ipList, int ip)
{
   return BinarySearch(source, ip, 0, ipList.Count - 1);
}

public static IPRange BinarySearch(IList<IPRange> ipList, int ip, int min, int max)
{      
   if (min > max)
   {
     throw new Assertion("Error: ipList is empty, out-of-order, or does not contain an element that includes the IP");
   } 
   int mid = (min + max) / 2;
   var midIp = ipList[mid];
   if (ip < midIp.BeginIpNum)
   {
     return BinarySearch(ipList, ip, min, mid-1);
   }
   if (ip > midIp.EndIpNum)
   {
     return BinarySearch(ipList, ip, mid+1, max);
   }
   return midIp; 
}
```

Comment: Any superior additional information vs http://stackoverflow.com/a/27067312/1413395 ?